# Need help in extracting the object from nested JSON in pysaprk

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark-sql

My JSON column values are as below

[{"item":"54509485","id":"1234","rule":"9383","issue_type":[],"rule_message":"this is json data.","sample_attributes":["shicode","measurement"],"impacted":[["Child"],[]],"type_of_blocker":[]}]

I want to get only object "item", "rule", "sample_attributes" using pyspark code using dataframe

Answer (score 0):

If you got pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame, you can do it by:

```
data.select(data.column_name.item, data.column_name.rule, data.column_name.sample_attributes)
```

Where *data* is your dataframe, and *column_name* is name of your column.